# Can not install deepface because package versions have conflict

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install deepface on mac m1. I have installed `tensorflow-macos` and current version is 2.5.0. But when I try to install deepface it says that there is a conflict in dependencies versions like `deepface 0.0.65 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0`.
But as per my understanding, I've already installed `tensorflow-macos 2.5.0`
So why is there is a conflict ?

And please give me any solutions.

```
ERROR: Cannot install deepface==0.0.1, deepface==0.0.10, deepface==0.0.11, deepface==0.0.12, deepface==0.0.13, deepface==0.0.14, deepface==0.0.15, deepface==0.0.16, deepface==0.0.18, deepface==0.0.19, deepface==0.0.2, deepface==0.0.20, deepface==0.0.21, deepface==0.0.22, deepface==0.0.23, deepface==0.0.24, deepface==0.0.25, deepface==0.0.26, deepface==0.0.3, deepface==0.0.30, deepface==0.0.31, deepface==0.0.32, deepface==0.0.33, deepface==0.0.34, deepface==0.0.35, deepface==0.0.36, deepface==0.0.37, deepface==0.0.38, deepface==0.0.39, deepface==0.0.4, deepface==0.0.40, deepface==0.0.41, deepface==0.0.43, deepface==0.0.44, deepface==0.0.45, deepface==0.0.46, deepface==0.0.47, deepface==0.0.48, deepface==0.0.49, deepface==0.0.5, deepface==0.0.50, deepface==0.0.51, deepface==0.0.52, deepface==0.0.53, deepface==0.0.54, deepface==0.0.55, deepface==0.0.56, deepface==0.0.57, deepface==0.0.58, deepface==0.0.59, deepface==0.0.6, deepface==0.0.60, deepface==0.0.61, deepface==0.0.62, deepface==0.0.63, deepface==0.0.64, deepface==0.0.65, deepface==0.0.7 and deepface==0.0.9 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    deepface 0.0.65 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.64 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.63 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.62 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.61 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.60 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.59 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.58 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.57 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.56 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.55 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.54 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.53 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.52 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.51 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.50 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.49 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.48 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.47 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.46 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.45 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.44 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.43 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.41 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.40 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.39 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.38 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.37 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.36 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.35 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.34 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.33 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.32 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.31 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.30 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.26 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.25 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.24 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.23 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.22 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.21 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.20 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.19 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.18 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.16 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.15 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.14 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.13 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.12 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.11 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.10 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.9 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.7 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.6 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.5 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.4 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.3 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.2 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
    deepface 0.0.1 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Comment: How did you install the Deep face? Try to install it using `pip install deepface`. Follow the reference link to resolve the conflicts as error code shows [reference](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies) link at the bottom.

Comment: try to call pip command with no dependencies: pip install deepface --no-deps

Comment: Did you install tensorflow according to the standard procedure for installing TF on a macos?

Answer (score 2):

try installing deepface using

```
pip install --no-deps deepface
```

this will download deepface library without any dependecy.

Answer (score 1):

try to install tf for mac first

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

then install deepface without dependencies

```
pip install deepface --no-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

First try installing tensorflow if you haven’t already . This worked for me , I was facing the same issue while installing deepface module.

```
pip install tensorflow
```